# Array of String splits

Tags: java, arrays

I'm still quite new to Java, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Given a .txt file, I am aiming to assign each word in a line of text into an array, and then each of those arrays into a parent array, which sorts it into

```
word[linenum-1][wordnum-1]
```

Example, given this text file:

> Hello, my
>
> name is Fred and
>
> I like
>
> to eat pie.

It will align them into arrays as follows:

```
word[0][0]="Hello,"

word[0][1]="my"

word[1][0]="name"

word[1][1]="is"

word[1][2]="Fred"

word[1][3]="and"

word[2][0]="I"

word[2][1]="like"

word[3][0]="to"

word[3][1]="eat"

word[3][2]="Pie"
```

Upon attempting this, I continually end up with NullPointerExceptions when I call my method.
Here is my code:

```
public static String word[][];

private static void splitFile(String infile) throws IOException
{
    lineCount = lineNum(infile);

    buffered = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
    for (i=0;i<lineCount;i++)
    {
        String[] temparray = buffered.readLine().split(" ");
        word[i] = temparray.clone();
    }
    buffered.close();
}
```

I have confirmed that lineNum work, as does readLine.

Comment: Your friend ran into a [slightly different problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333328/null-when-using-split).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing initialization of `word` array,

First of all, after reading number of lines, initialize it for given count - `words = new String[lineCount][];`.

Secondly, You don't have to clone the array that was created by split, so

```
String[] temparray = buffered.readLine().split(" ");
word[i] = temparray.clone();
```

can be safetly changed to `word[i] = buffered.readLine().split(" ")`.

Of course this assumes that `lineNum` returns correct number (safety check for negative and `0` is advised) and `readLine()` won't return `null`